# GHCI Breakpoint Trouble

Tags: haskell, ghci

Here is a toy function, defined in a file, call it test.hs:

```
x a b c = do
  putStrLn $ show a
  return a
```

One can of course import it into GHCI and set a breakpoint:

```
λ :load test.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( test.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
λ :break x
Breakpoint 3 activated at test2.hs:(1,1)-(3,12)
λ x 1 2 3
Stopped at test2.hs:(1,1)-(3,12)
_result :: IO b = _
```

Yet there appears to not be a way to inspect arguments b and c.

Is there any way around this? I am running GHCi 7.8.4.

Answer (score 3):

From the [GHC user's guide](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci-debugger.html):

> GHCi has provided bindings for the free variables[6] of the expression
>   on which the breakpoint was placed ...
>
> [6] We originally provided bindings for all variables in scope, rather
>   than just the free variables of the expression, but found that this
>   affected performance considerably, hence the current restriction to
>   just the free variables.

Comment: Thanks! I read part of this page but missed the footnote. I wonder if there is some way to re-enable the functionality (even at a performance loss).

Answer (score 2):

I have found a hacky workaround. If one redefines the function x as follows:

```
x a b c = do
    return a; return b; return c;
    putStrLn $ show a
    return a
```

Then one must call :step and then b and c can be inspected:

```
λ :break x
Breakpoint 4 activated at test2.hs:(1,1)-(4,12)
λ x 1 2 3
Stopped at test2.hs:(1,1)-(4,12)
_result :: IO b = _
λ :step
Stopped at test2.hs:(1,11)-(4,12)
_result :: IO Integer = _
a :: Integer = 1
b :: Integer = 2
c :: Integer = 3
```

It could be nice if there were a way to do this without redefining the function, however.